# How to get solana rpc url?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, blockchain, bitcoin, solana, cryptocurrency

I am a beginner to solana . I am creating a extension so I want to get some ideas from [this](https://github.com/rjpeterson/mango-markets-watch) repo . As mentioned in that repo's readme to "replace rpcToken in connection.ts with your own solana rpc url" . I want to know how do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your active RPC like this (assuming you have [Solana-CLI](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools) installed)
`solana config get | grep RPC`. You can also change it to whatever you need via `solana config set --url [URL]` for example to devnet like `solana config set --url devnet` aka `config set --url https://api.devnet.solana.com`

Comment: Thank you but [here] (https://github.com/rjpeterson/mango-markets-watch/blob/c3a33c9d9ebeaf50c407cf538428999f3d5d3365/src/background/connection.ts#L1) it has mango .. How can I get this

Comment: https://mango.rpcpool.com/ looks like normal Solana RPC service so it basically says it can be replaced with any other RPC as https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com . At least that's how I understand it. Note it also expects some process.env.TOKEN  set.